# Boost::Program_Options unhandled exception due to access violation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have a program that runs fine in DEBUG mode but in RELEASE mode I get an unhandled exception due to an access violation. I'm pretty sure it's not due to null pointers. Here is the call stack:

```
msvcr90d.dll!memchr(unsigned char * buf=0x0000002c, unsigned char chr='', unsigned long cnt=1243588)  Line 80         Asm
msvcp90d.dll!std::char_traits<char>::find(const char * _First=0x72656d6f, unsigned int _Count=15, const char & _Ch=',')  Line 590 + 0x15 bytes     C++
msvcp90d.dll!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::_DebugHeapAllocator<char> >::find(const char * _Ptr=0x0012f9e4, unsigned int _Off=0, unsigned int _Count=1)  Line 1796 + 0x2d bytes  C++
Program.exe!boost::program_options::option_description::set_name()  + 0x61 bytes   C++
Program.exe!boost::program_options::option_description::option_description()  + 0x90 bytes C++
Program.exe!boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()()  + 0x58 bytes           C++
Program.exe!CommandLineInput(int count=2, char * * vector=0x003d3360)  Line 191 + 0xac bytes          C++
Program.exe!main(int argc=4233952, char * * argv=0x00000002)  Line 65535        C++
Program.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 582 + 0x17 bytes            C
```

Code:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        try
        {
            CommandInput (argc, argv); //get command line input
        }
        catch ( std::exception e )
        {
            std::cout << "WARNING: Exception is thrown" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
}

void CommandInput (int count, _TCHAR* vector[])
{
        po::options_description desc("Available Parameters");
        std::cout << "\n";
        desc.add_options()
            ("option1", po::value<std::string>(), "description1")
            ("option2", po::value<std::string>(), "description2")
            ("option3", po::value<std::string>(), "description3");

/*
The code breaks at the above line
*/
}
```

The exception reads:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x1026f09b (msvcr90d.dll) in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x72656d6f.
```

Comment: The problem is work related so I was reluctant to post any code. But now I edited my post to insert mock code that resembles what the actual code looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem I may be facing is that my program loads the symbols from the DEBUG CRT DLL's. By the time the access violation occurs, the symbols from the RELEASE CRT DLL's are not loaded. I have checked all the projects involved in my program and they all use a Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) and yet it's still using the debug version of it.

Comment: I have found the problem. It seems that I was linking to debug Boost libraries in my project's property pages ("libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_42.lib" was the culprit). I fixed it by going to Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies and changed the library names to point to the Release versions.

Answer (score 0):

Something's funky.  Why is argc 4233952?  Can you verify that that is not just an artifact of the debugger?

I suggest you rebuild your project, and if that doesn't fix it, then debug the program after everything is loaded and look at the "modules" window.  You may be mixing incompatible libraries, e.g. release and debug versions of DLL's/EXE's.

Pay special attention to the CRT files that were loaded, msvcr90d, etc.  Look at the file version info of all the CRT DLL's that were loaded and verify that they all have the same version.

Comment: Hi David, I'm not sure what you mean by "an artifact of the debugger". Can you clarify this? Also, the modules that were loaded were system DLL's so I don't think there is an issue with mixing DEBUG and RELEASE DLL's. The CRT DLL's had the same version number, but I think I found something fishy. I my program (running in RELEASE) has loaded the symbols of DEBUG CRT DLL's (found in the "x86_Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_597c3456" folder) but not the symbols of the CRT DLL's in the "x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_597c3456" folder.

Comment: Also, argv has the value 0x00000002... it looks like the two might have gotten swapped? An argc of 2 and an argv of 0x00409AE0 would make much more sense.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. However, I don't think it's the cause of the problem because the access violation error occurs before either parameter gets used (it breaks at the desc.add_options() line).

Comment: @Dan, I mean that the debugger attempts to guess the values of local variables and the call stack by looking at the CPU's registers and tracing through the stashed EBP and ESP values down to the bottom of the stack.  A function is not obligated to honor EBP and ESP during its own operation, so if a function optimizes register usage or uses a non-standard location to maintain stack information, the debugger will report incorrect information about local variables.